# Printing from WebView exactly same with normal browser

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, webkit, pretty-print

I am developing a cocoa app which has a WebView showing an HTML page which is not under my control.

This page has a special print button on the page and when the user has clicked on it page makes some JavaScript work to create a very clear view to be printed (Pretty print). On the other hand, if user uses the standard print function of normal browser, they get a different (not clear) full page print.

I am trying to get the same output of the pretty print function which is embedded into the page by using JavaScript.

When I used

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender printFrameView:(WebFrameView *)frameView
```

method I need provide the view to be printed like: **[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView]**

```
NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:[[[webView mainFrame] frameView] documentView] printInfo:printInfo];
```

My problem is when I provide my view to printOperationWithView parameter I get the standart printing like printing the all page from browser. However, I need to get exactly the same output when user has clicked on the special print function on the page.

I tried not handling

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender printFrameView:(WebFrameView *)frameView
```

in my code but this time the printing modal dialog is not shown.

Is there any way to handle such a case or not handling printing in my webview and getting the same output when I clicked on the print button embedded in the page from a standard browser (like redirecting the printing request to standard browser instead of handling in my code).